# Case insensitive search with wildcard in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just started working on elasticsearch. I have an index "new_index" with mapping given below :

```
"new_index" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "current" : {
        "properties" : {
          "did" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "fil_date" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "file_nr" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "mark_text" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "mark_type_id" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "markdescr" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "markdescrtext" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "niceclmain" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "owname" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "statusapplication" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1527665866982",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "Py5uWzVTRYqcZuCLcwm-BQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6020499"
        },
        "provided_name" : "new_index"
      }
    }
  }
```

now I want to search on field "mark_text". I have two types of search 1. If I search for "smart", result should only contain case insensitive words of "smart". 2. It should search as we use LIKE "%smart%" and also case insensitive.

I have got the query for 2nd searching case. But, I want to know if there is any solution which can be used for both search cases.

**EDIT** : 
The query I am using for search case 1 is :

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match": {
            "mark_text": "smart"
          }
        }  
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query for search case 2 :

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "mark_text": "*smart*"
          }
        }  
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the query you already have.

Comment: I have updated the question as you requested @Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new index and add mapping and settings as below :

```
{
  "new_index5" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "current" : {
        "properties" : {
          "did" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "fil_date" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "file_nr" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "filing_date" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "mark_identification" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "normalizer" : "lowercase_normalizer"
          },
          "mark_text" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "normalizer" : "lowercase_normalizer"
          },
          "mark_type_id" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "markdescr" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "markdescrtext" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "niceclmain" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "owname" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "normalizer" : "lowercase_normalizer"
          },
          "party_name" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "normalizer" : "lowercase_normalizer"
          },
          "primary_code" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "registration_date" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "registration_number" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "serial_number" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "status_code" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "statusapplication" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "new_index5",
        "creation_date" : "1527686957833",
        "analysis" : {
          "normalizer" : {
            "lowercase_normalizer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "char_filter" : [ ]
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "9YdUrs1cSBuqDJmvSPOm6g",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6020499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And Added aggregation in my query for first search case, like this :

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match": {
              "mark_text": "smart"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "mark_texts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mark_text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me results including "smart" and "SMART" both.

For second search case, I am using fuzzy.

I still don't know how aggregation and normalizers solved my probelm. But, I am trying to understand it.